# NodeJS and MAMP running on local machine. Is it possible?

Tags: macos, node.js, local, mamp

Is it possible to have NodeJS and MAMP running together on the same machine?  If so how would i achieve this?

Note: I can run them separately just not together.  I assume its down to my NodeJS using the "localhost" as well as MAMP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can setup Proxy and a host.

for example create node01.example.com in Hosts. Then Go to Advanced and enter the following in "Customized virtual host general settings"

```
ServerAlias node01.example.com

 <Location />

  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/

ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000/

</Location>
```

when you visit node01.example.com you'd pass through MAMP and go to your node ;)

Comment: I've added node01.example.com in my /etc/hosts and created a new Host as you mentioned above but it still goes to my PHP subdirectory and doesn't forward to :3000 . Any ideas?

Comment: you don't need to create any additional hosts in /etc/hosts. Just make sure there isn't any other Host under Mamp responding to the request. This is the exact code I'm using.

Comment: Any way of also sending headers with this?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you want NodeJs to do?

Are you using NodeJS to work as a webserver?

You could set it to run on another port number - this would let you access it through:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Then visit http://localhost:1337