# How to stop mamp pro overriding localhost:3000?

Tags: node.js, npm, mamp, mamp-pro

I am trying to get an existing node website working for me locally with mamp pro. The first developer used the non-pro version of mamp and it works fine for him. But when I visit http://localhost:3000/ after "npm start" I am served with the mamp pro default "The virtual host was set up successfully" page. Is there a way I can prevent mamp pro superseding localhost or even just that port? (I tried the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739183/nodejs-and-mamp-running-on-local-machine-is-it-possible/14131768#14131768) and [here](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/11/how-to-proxy-node-js-requests-in-mamp-mamp-pro/) but it just redirected it to the mamp default page again.) Webpack.config settings here:

```
proxy: [
  {
    context: [
      '**',
      '!/*.js',
      '!/*.css',
      '!/__webpack_hmr',
      '!/*.hot-update.js',
      '!/*.hot-update.json',
    ],
    options: {
      target: 'http://example.local:8888/',
      autoRewrite: true,
      // Review docs before setting these
      // changeOrigin: true,
      // logLevel: 'error'
    },
  },
],
```

},